# Ok to hook up water filters to a regular kitchen faucet?

Tags: water, kitchens, faucet, filter

So we have this beautiful Grohe Minta (sort of upside down 7-shaped) kitchen faucet. We want to add a drinking water faucet next to it, but cannot find any filtered water faucet that goes with the Minta's looks.

So, I'm thinking of buying another kitchen or prep faucet, connect the cold water hose to the filters and cap the hot water connection.

Is this ok to do? Permissible? 
Any issues we should be aware of? Flow, gpm? Connectors/adapters needed?
Here is a pic of the Grohe Minta:

[image]

Comment: Maybe worth considering: just get a filter designed to be installed on the cold water side of your existing faucet. Simple, no need for another faucet. For example: https://www.amazon.com/Woder-10K-Gen3-Capacity-Connect-Filtration/dp/B0144MFPOA

Comment: @ShimonRura They may want to avoid running ALL the water - e.g., for washing dishes - through the filter. On the other hand, the filter you linked to is pretty good and works out to about $0.01 per gallon - a LOT less than typical Brita pitcher filters or even typical refrigerator filters.

Comment: I question the need for filtering any US standard public treated water source for drinking water. Just drink the water from the tap, unless you have a known problem in your supply.

Comment: The question is valid even for a hard water faucet, for example. Whether there's a filter attached is tangential.

Comment: @JimStewart Fortunately in the US, with extremely rare exceptions, tap water is 100% safe for nearly everyone. But there are a LOT of people who prefer the **taste** of filtered water, and a **huge** industry ready to serve them.

Comment: @JimStewart I always drank unfiltered water until I saw my pool being filled.  It may be safe, but it’s not exactly clean and en-masse was pretty green.  This was evident after just a few hours and several feet of depth against a fresh clean white pool bottom.  It changed my opinion permanently.

Comment: Installing a filter will cause a flow reduction on a regular kitchen faucet; the *amount* of reduction depends on the filter type. Just be aware of this if you install an in-line filter on your primary faucet that you use for washing up, filling pots, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Good idea. There's really no problem with that approach aside from the stagnant water that will accumulate in the faucet's hot water stub, which could be a health concern (or just gross).

Instead, split your filtered water supply and run it to both the hot and cold sides of the faucet. This has the additional benefit of making the faucet flow full in all temperature modes.

Comment: Jim Stewart. The chlorine smell and taste of tap water is awful for peeps who didn't grow up with it: swimming pool water yuck! Thing is the town messed with the street valve to our lead pipe , so now they tell us, that we have to either run the water for 5 min. before drinking/cooking, or filter the lead out. It's outrageous that lead pipes weren't banned in the 60s, as, since the 20s, they were a known health threat. Leaded paint was only banned in the 70s, gasoline much much later!  Yet again, people vote for politicians who promise to get rid of those  "unnecessary" regulations. Go figure!

Answer (score 0):

I installed a whirlpool filter #WHKF-DWHBB, item #631984 that I purchased from Lowes, on the cold side of the kitchen faucet, about 10 years ago. I change the filter every 6 months. I installed the filter since we do not like the taste of the city water. The replacement filter is the one that is for taste and odor only (charcoal). The water tastes as good as bottled water. My 2 cents

Comment: This doesn't really address the question, which is about using just one side of a faucet.

Comment: @isherwood-- the cold side is only one side of the faucet. The filtered water flows only through the cold supply line.